# Finding the longest palindrome from the given string

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings, palindrome, memory-optimization

Recently I came across [this problem](http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/LONGPALIN) which instructs me to find the longest substring which is a palindrome:

> As we all know, a palindrome is a word that equals its reverse. Here
>   are some examples of palindromes: malayalam, gag, appa, amma.
>
> We consider any sequence consisting of the letters of the English
>   alphabet to be a word. So axxb,abbba and bbbccddx are words for our
>   purpose. And aaabbaaa, abbba and bbb are examples of palindromes.
>
> By a subword of a word, we mean a contiguous subsequence of the word.
>   For example the subwords of the word abbba are a, b, ab, bb, ba, abb,
>   bbb, bba, abbb, bbba and abbba.
>
> In this task you will given a word and you must find the longest
>   subword of this word that is also a palindrome.
>
> For example if the given word is abbba then the answer is abbba. If
>   the given word is abcbcabbacba then the answer is bcabbacb.

I got this with dynamic programming, but for larger test cases it seems I am breaking the memory barrier. When the length is about 4500, it gives me a segmentation fault. That's probably because 4500 x 4500 = 20250000, which is about \$2*10^7\$, and the size of my boolean array is too much in front of the imposed memory limit of 64 MB.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

void longestpalin(std::string str,int n){
    bool table[n][n];                   //boolean table for keeping records of palindromes 
    std::memset(table,0,sizeof(table));

    int maxLength = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        table[i][i] = true; // obviously every letter is palindrome of itself
    }

    int start = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        if(str[i] == str[i+1]){
            table[i][i+1] = true; //two letters repeated is also a palindrome
            maxLength = 2;
            start = i;
        }
    }

    for(int k=3;k <= n;k++){
        for(int i=0;i<n-k+1;i++){
            int j = i + k - 1;
            if(table[i+1][j-1]&&str[i] == str[j]){//checking whether the middle letters are in a pallindrome or not
                table[i][j] = true; 
                if(k > maxLength){
                    maxLength = k;
                    start = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << maxLength << std::endl;
    std::cout << str.substr(start,maxLength) << std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::string word;
    std::cin >> word;
    longestpalin(word,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a better approach to avoid a segmentation fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> bool table[n][n];                   //boolean table for keeping records of palindromes
> ```

Variable-length arrays are [not part of the C++ standard, and in any case they are a bad idea](//stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/1157100).  ([Some C++ compilers support it anyway](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla) as a non-standard feature.)  Stacks aren't meant to handle such large frames.  If you need a large variable-length array, use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or a [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) instead.

Comment: thats it , never going to use c style arrays after it , lesson learnt.

Comment: If you have some time can you please take a look at [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143443/code-for-calculating-number-of-unharmed-leaves) query of mine?

Answer (score 2):

You will hit a 64MB memory restriction regardless of how you allocate an array 20+ million entries strong. So you need to revisit an algorithm.

The problem doesn't look like a DP to begin with. Notice that the mere initialization of the array drives the time complexity to be quadratic. If you are happy with the quadratic time, notice that a naive approach requires constant space.

And since the quadratic time complexity will TLE on any decent OJ, you shall check out [Manacher's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring).

Comment: saw Manacher's algorithm in geeks for geeks website but it is beyond my understanding , hence I tried the DP solution ,and DP will be enough for IOI isnt it?